# How to filter based and facep_wrap based on multiple column values in R (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, conditional-statements

I’m working with a dataset and want to use ggplot geom_point to visualize my data for two out of 5 groups in column “title” and facet_wrap based on "NewSess" and "title".  So far I have written:

```
ggplot(CMdata[CMdata$title == 'SAFARI', 'CHROME'], aes(x = Sales, y = Product.Views)) +
geom_point() +
facet_wrap(~NewSess, title)
```

ggplot doesn’t let me facet_wrap the data by the two conditions.

```
Sales   NewNess   title    Product.Views
 100       Y      SAFARI       822
 90        N      CHROME       962
 190       Y      CHROME       213
 190       N      SAFARI       332
 100       N        IE         329
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `CMdata[CMdata$title %in% c('SAFARI','CHROME'),]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
ggplot(CMdata[CMdata$title %in% c('SAFARI','CHROME'),], aes(x = sales, y = Product.Views)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(NewNess ~title)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but had to change the facet_wrap syntax slightly to    `facet_wrap(~title + NewSess)`